# how to change the TotalItemCount in PagedCollectionView in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datapager

I am trying to do paging in datagrid silverlight
I am using PagedCollectionView for paging.

```
 <sdk:DataPager Name="RequestDataPager" PageSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding Path=PagedRequestRepFamilies}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding ElementName=RequestDataGrid, Path=ActualWidth}"></sdk:DataPager>
```

My Req :

Here for 1 st time when datagrid loaded, it fetches Top 10 Records event though it's record count is 100

I need to change the item count to 100 instead of 10 when I am trying to change the itemcount it's saying itemcount property is readonly and cannot change.

when I click page 2 it should go to database and fetch back the next 10 records and the itemcount should still be 100 and it should go on..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer :

Create CurrentPageIndex property as Integer in ViewModel:

I am passing the pageindex and page size to the service and returns the 100 Records as :

```
result.Response = result.Response.Skip(Pageindex * pagesize).Take(pagesize).ToList()

Private Sub RequestDataGrid_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RequestDataPager.PageIndexChanging
        Dim str As String = String.Empty
        If Not GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).Pageindexchanged Then
            If (RequestDataPager.PageIndex +1) >= 1 Then
                GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).GRDPager = RequestDataPager                
                GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).Pageindexchanged = False
                GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).PageindexLoadingrow = False
                GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).IsCallRequestRepFamily = False
            End If
        End If

        'RequestDataPager.PageIndex = GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).RecordCount
    End Sub
```

In PageIndexChanging you cannot get the Current Page index, to get the current page index in the loading row event:

```
 Private Sub RequestDataGrid_LoadingRow(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs) Handles RequestDataGrid.LoadingRow
        e.Row.Header = e.Row.GetIndex + 1 + (CType(RequestDataGrid.DataContext, RequestListViewModel).PagedRequestRepFamilies.PageIndex * CType(RequestDataGrid.DataContext, RequestListViewModel).PagedRequestRepFamilies.PageSize)

        If Not GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).Pageindexchanged Then
            If Not GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).PageindexLoadingrow Then
                GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).CurrentPageIndex = RequestDataPager.PageIndex
                If Not GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).IsCallRequestRepFamily Then
                    GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).FindRequestRepFamilies(GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).SelectedRepFamilies)
                    GetDataContext(Of RequestListViewModel).IsCallRequestRepFamily = True
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

IsCallRequestRepFamily , Pageindexchanged properties are managed accordingly in the call back of the FindRequestRepFamilies

I am settign the page count for datagridpager in viewmodel after binding the collection as    `GRDPager.PageIndex = CurrentPageIndex`